# is there an option to unwind only when the array isn't empty?

Tags: mongodb

i'm trying to run query with unwind. (aggregation)
the problem is that when i'm running unwind on an empty array I get empty result.
I know that this is a problem:

> If the array holds an empty array ([]) in an input document, the
>   pipeline ignores the input document and will not output documents for
>   that input document. (from MongoDB docs)

is there an option that i can run 'unwind' only when the array i'm trying to unwind isn't empty?

EDIT:

```
$match = [
  '_id' => ['$in' => $ids]
];

$project = [
  'name' => true,
  'sum1' => true,
  'array1' => true,
  'array2' => true,
  'array3' => true
];

$group = [
  '_id' => '$name',
  'sum1' => ['$sum' => '$sum1'],
  'array1' =>  ['$push' => '$array1'],
  'array2' =>  ['$push' => '$array2'],
  'array3' =>  ['$push' => '$array3']
];

$query = [
  ['$match' => $match],
  ['$project' => $project],
  ['$group' => $group],
  ['$unwind' => '$array1'],
  ['$unwind' => '$array2'],
  ['$unwind' => '$array3']
];

$ret = mongo_get_db()
  ->selectCollection("collection")
  ->aggregate($query);
```

EDIT2:

```
{
    name: ‘name1’
    sum1: 2
    array1: 
    [
        {
            id: 111
            name: 222
        }   
    ]
    array2: []
    array3: []
}

{
    name: ‘name1’
    sum1: 10
    array1: 
    [
        {
            id: 122
            name: 333
        }
    ]
    array2: []
    array3: []
}
```

RESULT:

```
{
    name: ‘name1’
    sum1: 12
    array1:
    [
        {
            id: 111
            name: 222
        }
        {
            id: 122
            name: 333
        }
    ]
    array2: []
    array3: []
}
```

tnx :)

Comment: The second question adding default item if the array is empty. If I'll do unwind to array with default item, I'll get not the result I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match) operator prior to the [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind) that filters documents which have the array that has at least an element, using the logic that there exists at least the first element indexed 0 in the array (with the **[dot notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation)**):

```
{ $match: { "array_field.0": { $exists: true } } };
```

Comment: It's a problem: I have 3 arrays (that I want to unwind them). But not all the the documents have this arrays. So if some documents don't include this empty array I still want to get the document  but not to unwind the array.

Comment: Can you edit your question to reproduce the issue with some sample documents and the expected result?

Comment: @DorAtias Thanks for updating your question, is it ok for you to include some sample documents and the expected output?

Comment: i added two documents and the expected result

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply check if the array is empty?

```
if(myArray.length === 0) { /* call your code here */ }
```

Comment: It's in mongo query. I don't sure I can add this to the query.